# Implementing an or where condition in yii2 find

Tags: php, yii2

Am performing a find() in yii2 I understand that there can be andwhere but what of orWher

I have tried

```
$query = Tblpr::find()->where(['PRID'=>2])->andwhere(['new'=>1])->all();
```

How can i implement orWhere

Comment: Sorry i had some internet problems thanks it works

Comment: No Problem. *Enjoy Coding.*

Comment: Kindly check this question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915060/showing-kartik-growl-via-ajax-in-yii2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Where OR`

```
$query = Tblpr::find();
$query->andFilterWhere(['or',
                    ['PRID',2],
                    ['new',1]
                  ])->all();
```

OR

```
$query = Tblpr::find()->select('*')
          ->orWhere(['PRID'=>2,'new'=>1])->all();
```

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148550/filtering-yii2-grid-using-a-form-with-related-model

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `createCommand`

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select('*')
                ->from('Tblpr') // put your table name here
                ->where(['PRID'=>[2]])
                ->orWhere(['new'=>[1]]);
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        print_r ($command->sql);die;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for a query with `->where()` and `->orWhere()`

```
$query = Tblpr::find()
    ->where(['PRID' => 2])
    ->orWhere(['attribute' => 'value'])
    ->all();
```