# Showing kartik growl via ajax in yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Am using kartik growl and i would like to show the growl via ajax success

I have tried

This is the **javascript** code:

```
$.post({
  url: "forwardpr", // your controller action
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {keylist: keys,user:userdata},
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    //$.pjax.reload({container:'#forward-grid'});
    $.growl( data.growl );
  },
  error: function(err){
  alert(err);
  console.log("server error");
  }
});
```

This is the **controller** code:

```
$growl = [
  'title' => "Group members updated.<hr>",
  'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign',
  'message' => "Successifully updated.",
  'showSeparator' => true,
];

echo json_encode(['response'=>"Successifully forwarded pr(s)", 'growl' => $growl ]);
```

Comment: So, what problem you are facing @geof ?

Comment: I think. Instead of `echo json_encode(` you should do `return json_encode(` .

Comment: The growl is not actually showing

Comment: Actually, I don't have idea on GROWL. So, can't help much as I'm not aware of behaviour of GROWL.

Comment: So what about on the console i get $.growl is not a function

Comment: Yes. First time seeing any `$.growl`. That's why. Where you wanted to put response information. Show me. I will help you.

Comment: I want the response information to show using kartik growl, the $.growl is in the code i have posted on the success function

Comment: Ill try that and tell you later

Comment: May be I think, you hve to use that growl ID. and do like this and check. `$("#growl-id").html(data.growl);`

Comment: Are your variables `keys` and `userdata` defined? Because in case at least one isn't your growl will not be displayed.

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot, Thanks it works

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI I'm glad it worked, mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see `TypeError: $.growl is not a function`, then it means you have not included required files to **AppAsset.php** file.

To solve this problem, go to **assets/AppAsset.php** file and add:

```
public $css = [
        // ... Something else might be here
        'css/jquery.growl.css',
    ];
```

And

```
public $js = [
        // Something else might be here
        'js/core.js',
    ];
```

Because of missing `.js` file, you have that error in console (`TypeError: $.growl is not a function`). But you also must add `.css` file as well because without it you will not see growl, even though it works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using the wrong function. Here's offical [docs](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/):

> "Another important update is since version 3.x you no longer call the
>   plugin using $.growl(...) you must use $.notify(...)."

In another words, just try using **$.notify**(...) instead of **$.growl**(...).